# Stopping AWS Cloudwatch INSUFFICIENT_DATA to OK transition emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, amazon-cloudwatch

With Cloudwatch alarms I want to know about ALARM -> OK transition, but INSUFFICIENT_DATA -> OK transition just gets really annoying.

Is there a way to stop the latter notification? I could do via an email filter but would rather stop it at the source if possible.

Comment: this creates instability and makes AWS make more money as instances gets more often stopped and started

Comment: This makes **alarms** much less effective.

Comment: AWS support have said that the reason for this behaviour is that in CloudWatch 0 is never stored as a metric for anything, so this explains this behaviour :-(

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the answer appears to be:

> Currently, this isn't possible though it is an interesting request.

from this forum answer on the 21st of January 2013:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=417727

Answer (score 2):

In 2018 AWS launched metric math. Since that the problem could be solved with `FILL()` function. The function replaces empty (INSUFFICIENT_DATA) points with constant values.

[CW metric example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvfu3.png)

`m1` is a raw CloudWatch metric which contains holes in the time series. 
`e1` is a math metric and has zeros instead of empty points.

Using Metric Math:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html

Detailed explanation how to create a metric math alarms:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/create-a-metric-math-alarm-using-amazon-cloudwatch/

The similar question: 
[AWS Cloudwatch Math Expressions: removing Insufficient Data: is there a "coalesce" function like SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494366/aws-cloudwatch-math-expressions-removing-insufficient-data-is-there-a-coalesc)

Comment: the FILL function must be specified in uppercase ! Even in Terraform.

eg         expression = "FILL(m2, 0) - FILL(m1,0)"