# AWS Cloudwatch Math Expressions: removing Insufficient Data: is there a "coalesce" function like SQL?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, cloudwatch-alarms

Can I replace a None/Insufficient data point as a value (constant is fine) in a Cloudwatch Math Expression?

I am using a math expression of several metrics: if's, arithmetic, etc.

The problem is that you are now bound by all of the variables having sufficient data. If one is missing a datapoint, WHAM! Insufficient data for that math expression.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like the following based on the standard SQL `coalesce` function:

`coalsece(m1, m2, 15) + coalesce(m3, 25) / coalesce(m4, 8)`

*PLEASE NOTE:* Cloudwatch's mechanism for handling Insufficient Data only covers the final value (the result of the math expression). I am looking to cover each individual value differently, allowing more than just `is breaching/is ok/last value/insufficient data`. Thus, [the question linked here is an insufficient answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639642/avoiding-insufficient-data-in-cloudwatch)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In general, you can perform math functions on > 1 variable, and they
   will apparently automatically fill in all gaps in the data with 0.
   However, if there is a simultaneous gap in the data, your output
   will be sparse.
2. The better answer is the `FILL()` function. In the example
   above, every variable would need to make a specific call to `FILL` multiple times, as `FILL` only takes two arguments: a metric and either a time series to fill with OR a scalar value:

```
FILL(FILL(m1, m2), 15) + FILL(m3, 25) / FILL(m4, 8)
```

Ref:
[Cloudwatch function discription. Search for the `FILL` function.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html)